# Compute folder size for a given file extension only

Tags: files, php, directory, find

I have a folder containing all my PHP projects, I'd like a command that would output the folder size of each project but only for the `*.php` files inside it. Ideally the output would be something like this:

```
project1 7,0M
project2 13,3M
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a folder that contains only project folders, you could run the following in that folder:

```
for proj in *; do
  phpfiles=$(find $proj -iname '*.php')
  size=$(du -ch $phpfiles | tail -n 1 | cut -d\t -f1)
  echo $proj $size
done
```

Explanation: we iterate over all project folders. In each folder, we find all `*.php` files. We compute the total size of these files, and output the project folder's name and the computed size.

In the first line I simply used `*` to iterate over all project folders. That's assuming your current working directory is a folder that contains only project folders. However, you could replace this with something more accurate, e.g., `for proj in /home/user/proj1 /var/www/proj2 /opt/proj3`, to iterate only over specific folders.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. The command `find $proj -iname '*.php'` finds all files in folder `$proj` that end in `.php` - easy and straightforward. What do you want to exclude exactly? If there are certain PHP files that you do not wish to take into account, say a file `exclude.php`, you could use for instance `find $proj -iname '*.php' -a ! -name 'exclude.php'` meaning "find all files in folder `$proj` whose case-insensitive name ends in `.php` AND that are NOT named `exclude.php`". Refer to `man find` for more infos. I'll happily help, if you can tell me more precisely what you need ;)

Comment: I mean exclude files in the main directory that contains all projects. (which is your remark with *) But it would be cool to list the project folders dynamically.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well for that we would need to come up with criteria that identify a project folder. For starters, you could use `for proj in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)` to iterate only over the *directories* (`-type d`) that are *exactly one level below the current working directory* (`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`), i.e., all folders in the current folder. To additionally exclude the folders `not_this_folder` and `nor_this_folder` below the current directory, you could use `for proj in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name not_this_folder ! -name nor_this_folder)`.

Answer (score 0):

No problem:

```
find /var/www/site/ -type f -name "*.php" -exec du -shc {} + | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

You can script this to make it show them all:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/
for i in $(find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type d)
do
    prjSz=$(find $i -type f -name "*.php" -exec du -shc {} + | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "${i:2}: $prjSz"
done
```